# Node position with listings overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I'm trying to add a label on a code listing.
I will have a listing labeled "Device A" and a listing labeled "Device B".

I was hoping to draw the label somewhere in the corner of the listing.
I tried doing this with a tikz overlay and succeeded.

However, when the listing is a float, and is too large to fit in the text such that latex moves it to another page, the tikz positions are wrong and the node is drawn where my listing would have been positioned initially, I think.

I verified that it is due to latex moving the listing because a pageclear fixes the problem.

What can I do to make the tikz positions correct?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

%  If you remove this, the label is positioned on page one.
%\clearpage 

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar= !,frame = single,float]
!\tikzmark{x1}!code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code
\end{lstlisting}


\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\node [fill=pink] (all) at ([xshift=\textwidth]x1) {Device A};
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to note that there is an extension to the tikzmark library which puts loads of marks inside a listings environment automatically.

Comment: I've been looking for that, but can't seem to find anything. Is it a specific version of tikzmark?

Comment: It's an additional library that you load after loading the tikzmark library.  It's been in the tikzmark package for a while.  You can see the documentation at the ctan page: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the `\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{... {Device A};}` in the `lstlisting` environment, inside the escaped LaTeX code introduced with the `escapechar`, appears to do what you want. I also switch to `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` in order to work with the standard `\tikzmark` command (otherwise, with your custom definition, you could have problems when you start using packages which rely on the standard `\tikzmark`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!, frame=single, float]
!\tikzmark{x1}%
 \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{
   \node [fill=pink] (all) at ([xshift=\textwidth]pic cs:x1) {Device A};
 }!code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code

code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I actually used `minted` in an `mdframe` in a `listing`, and to make it work in that case it suffices to place the `tikz` inside the listing, above the `mdframe`.