How to Add a TikZ Text Info Box at a Specific Line Inside a listing Environment
How to add a custom info box at a specific line inside a lstlisting environment using tikz in LaTeX. Currently, I'm able to create the listing environment and set up tikz, but I'm struggling to position the tikz text box accurately on the line I need within the listing. Ideally, all the text boxes should be left-aligned at the same X-coordinate within the listing. Below, I’ve included my CODE, the current OUTPUT, and the DESIRED OUTPUT I'm aiming for.
CODE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{lstlisting}
        
            public void run() {
                move();
                move();
                move();
                pickBeeper();
                turnLeft();
                move();
                move();
            }  
                  
    \end{lstlisting}
        
\end{document}

OUTPUT:

DESIRED OUTPUT:


Search for tikz listing overlay, or tikzmark. See e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604741/245790

thanks a lot. I will check this out

I recommend having a look at the tikzmark documentation https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark ; I've just browsed a few questions here and there's not one that I would point to as a general example - they're all a bit specific.

I think this is exactly answered in the Q&A linked by MS-SPO. If you think it is different, feel free to vote for reopening
